# Resharper 9 Convert to LINQ: method syntax

Tags: linq, resharper, resharper-9.0, linq-method-syntax

I've been using Resharper (c#) for many years and found the automatic convert-to-linq-expression feature extremely helpful.

I've recently upgraded to V9 of resharper and it is now using linq query syntax rather than the method syntax which is my preference.

Does anybody know of any options to force resharper into using the method syntax? I've tried googling and look into resharper options but have found nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set preference in Re-Sharper from option menu. Go to  Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Context Option

[image]

Let me know how it worked for you..